# I want to store image on mysql database as blob type by php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store image on mysql database by php as blob type, but the following error is shown:

> Warning: getimagesize(3272) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\0412\form.php on
>   line 15

I use the following code:

```
  if($_POST['upload'] == 'upload' ) {
     // connect to database
     mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db("image") or die(mysql_error());

     // name of the upload image
     $name = addslashes($_FILES['uploadImage']['name']);
     // image
     $image = addslashes( file_get_contents( $_FILES['uploadImage']['tmp_name']) );
     $size = getimagesize($_FILES['uploadImage']['size']);


     if( $size == FALSE ) {
        echo "NO image selected $form";  
     }
     else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadImage']['tmp_name'],"UploadImage/".$name);

        if( !( $result = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO image VALUES ('','$name','$image') ") ) ) {
           echo "uploading image problem $form";    
        }

        }
```

Comment: Why would you want to store an image in a database, anyways? Your filesystem is perfectly fine for doing so.

Comment: You have [asked this question before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460517/i-want-to-store-image-on-mysql-database-by-php-as-blob-type). People have commented saying you shouldn't store images in a database. I for one strongly urge you to take their advice and store images on disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$size = getimagesize($_FILES['uploadImage']['size']);
```

Needs to be:

```
$size = getimagesize($_FILES['uploadImage']['tmp_name']);
```

Instead. You're tripping up over the fact that `getimagesize()` gets the size of the image *from the image data itself*. All you've passed to it is a number indicating it's upload size in bytes.

The correct example above opens the image from it's temporary location, which is held in `tmp_name`.

Comment: Not a problem. As @aefxx says in his comment, it's _far_ better to store your files in your filesystem, not in a database for various reasons. Also, don't forget to [accept answers to your questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), present and future.

Comment: @N.B. I appreciate your efforts (thank you), but I don't think sabbir will take notice after more than two months :-P

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following code ::

```
if($_POST['upload'] == 'upload' ) {

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("image") or die(mysql_error());

    $name = addslashes($_FILES['uploadImage']['name']);
    $image = file_get_contents( $_FILES['uploadImage']['tmp_name']) ;

     if( !( $result = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO image VALUES ('','$name','$image')") ) )          echo "uploading image problem $form";    

}
```